# ssis swap some values in a data flow if they match a lookup table

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, transform, lookup

Here's my problem - Midstream in my data flow, we have some values in one column that we want to swap for other values based on a lookup table.

For example, if I had a rowset like this:

```
Key   Value
1     A
2     B
3     A
4     C
5     D
6     B
...   ...
```

If I had a lookup table in a SQL Server DB that looked like this:

```
Value1    Value2
C         Y
D         Z
```

Then I would want my package to swap only those values so the resulting data flow would look like this:

```
Key   Value
1     A
2     B
3     A
4     Y
5     Z
6     B
...   ...
```

What components would produce the simplest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lookup component and then:

- Set it up to Ignore Failure
- Values that do not match will return null for the lookup value
- Use a derived column expression to populate where the lookup succeeded

  `ISNULL(Value2) ? Value : Value2`